# WWW::Mechanize returning forbidden url error

Tags: perl, web-scraping

This is the URL 
https://trade.4over.com/orders/ajax/product_run_size.php?id_product=599983
I am trying to store its data using mechanize. It is returning forbidden error and when i am hitting it in browser it is giving response.
I am using WWW::Mechanize module.
Here is the code that I am using

```
my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
    $mech->add_header( 'User-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; nl; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13');
        $mech -> cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
        $mech->get($url);
        my $result = $mech->submit_form(
        form_number => 2,
        fields       =>
        {
            username  => 'username', # Name of the input field and value
            password => 'password',
        },
        button    => 'log_in' # Name of the submit button
        ); 
        my $content = encode 'utf8',$mech->decoded_content;
        return $content;
```

Comment: This page does not open in my browser. Does it open in yours? If not, did you expect that WWW::Mechanize could open a page that a browser can't?

Comment: Dude it is opening in my browser. It might using some cookies of my browser as i am logged in. BTW thanks for your response and down vote.

Comment: Ok, so do you have cookies setup with WWW::Mechanize? Also, you might have to spoof the `User-Agent` header.

Comment: yes, I did that but that's too not working.

Comment: Does the page work correctly in your browser if you disable javascript? Also, it might be related to the `Referer` header. I think `WWW::Mechanize` does send that header by default. So make sure that you haven't disabled it for some reason.

Comment: You didn't show a request that worked -- following the link you provided in a browser also gives 403 -- and you didn't show how you tried to recreate that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the solution. I was doing t wrong.
What I was doing is to submit form on this page while the form is at the home page.
Now i am submitting the form on home page and then using mech->get for this UR.
Its working. Thanks for all your responce.